# Setting default resolution on qemu virtual machine simulating ARM

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I'm using QEMU to simulate ARM environment.

But the default resolution is poor.

```
I want to know how I can change/set the default resolution of my QEMU.
```

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/377382/qemu-set-or-force-higher-screen-resolution-than-640x480

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, QEMU uses the resolution of the guest OS. So you need to change the resolution for the ARM environment as you would if not running in QEMU. At least, this was the case for me with Ubuntu Server running in QEMU.

Answer (score 1):

To set the graphic resolution in QEMU you have to setup the VGA rom used by QEMU:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153526

The few standard "-vga" options available in qemu are listed here:

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Options

More info:

https://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2013/05/custom_display_resolutions_in_qemu/
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=678582

The guest OS will later setup its own resolution after booting up too, that you can set in the kernel bootup prompt (inside grub2 /etc/default/grub's GRUB_GFXMODE and GRUB_GFXMODE parameters).   But for this best is to read up the specific distro of your ARM guest OS (which you did not mention).